# How to check a list of user either it is logged in or not?

Tags: c, linux, authentication

I have a function that is used to check a list of user either that user is logged in or not.(Roughly say, the user have an active connection to the server).

This is the code:

```
static int is_login(char *user)
{
    int found = 0;
    struct utmpx *u;
    setutxent();
    while ((u = getutxent())) {
            if ((strcmp(u->ut_user,user)==0) && (u->ut_type ==USER_PROCESS)) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
            } else  {
                    found =0;
            }
    }
    endutxent();
    return found;
}
```

Dont get this wrong. This code work fine. The only issue is when /var/run/utmp permission are not set as readable. eg: `chmod /var/run/utmp 600.`. Even worse if the server doesnt have utmp. Instead use a utmps. Is there any other function that can do the same thing as `getutxent()`? So far what I only found is `getpwuid(getuid())` and `getlogin()` which only return the user that logged in on the controlling terminal.

This is what I have tested

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;
    struct passwd *pass;
    while(pass = getpwuid(getuid())) //I've tested also with getlogin(), but without the struct ofcourse.
    {
            name = pass->pw_name;
            printf("user = %s\n",name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While running this test program, I logged in with 2 more different user into that system, but those 2 user's name doesnt appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the project with the same functionality as yours (e.g. login events monitoring), but I have to rely onto the `/var/log/secure` file. It provides much more information for me. May be you should take it into account.